# Can you please help me with this series in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, math, numbers, series, successor-arithmetics

I need to print the result for this series: 2, 4, 7, 28, 33, 198...

When x is 1 result should be 2

When x is 2 result should be 4

When x is 3 result should be 7

And so on

I have this but it's not working:

```
    n = int(input( "Enter value N: "))
    r = 0
    for i in range(1,n+1):
      if(n%2==0):
        r=r*i
      else:
        r=r+i
    print(r)
```

Comment: You want your `print(r)` statement *inside* the loop. Therefore it should be indented so that it lines up with `if` and `else` inside the `for i` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With n=6 the following code print: 2, 4, 7, 28, 33 and 198.

```
n = int(input("Enter value N: "))
r = 1
for i in range(1, n+1):
    if i%2==0:
        r*=i
    else:
        r+=i
    print(r)
```